# View Controller not full screen

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios8, iphone-5

I have an iOS app that I inherited from a previous developer. It was originally created more than 3 years ago. When I run it in the simulator the view controllers all fill the screen as expected no matter which device I pick. But when I run it on my iPhone 5s running iOS 8.1 the view controllers are 320x480. Even `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` claims that the screen is 320x480. On the iPhone 5s simulator `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` reports the expected 320x568 screen size. All the view controllers are now in a Storyboard file if that means anything to anyone.

Is this just a bug in iOS that I have to wait for Apple to fix or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out there where several things against me. One I didn't notice that our artist gave me a bunch of files with no image data in them. Also in the projects `Target->General->App Icons and Launch Images` I had to manually tell it to use the AppIcon and LaunchImage in the assets file. If you click on the arrow next to where it says AppIcon or LaunchImage and nothing happens its because Xcode doesn't know what resource your linking to even if its name is in the selection box.